# Targeting nth element in CSS with specific sub element type? #content article article article

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have dynamic posts loading on wordpress. The posts are in an element 'article'. Testing the CSS on jsfiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/aS4me/ but on the live site, it does not work, it always targets the second piece of content.

Sample:
http://brookfield.wpengine.com/properties/

Current CSS:
`

```
    #content > article {

        min-height: 30px;
    }
    #content > article:nth-child(4n+4) { 
        margin-right: 0;
        background:red;
    }
```

`

Comment: Always include all relevant markup and rules **in** the question, don't just link (not even to jsFiddle). A fiddle is a nice adjunct, not a substitute.

Comment: Your production code is exactly the same as your JSFiddle code? I can't see any part of that sample website that looks like your JSFiddle.

Comment: not sure exactly what your articles in the actual site are, but if they are the items (with thumbnail) then the `background:red` may not be visible to your eyes because of some image laying on top.

Comment: The articles load dynamically on the bottom (Anything after 4 properties is dynamic). I'm trying to target the dynamic articles. The code selectors are the same, but the css being applied is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That`s because nth-child does not mean nth-of-type :)

It may be harder to wrap your head around this one, but your code (article:nth-child(4n+4)) finds the 4n+4 element (div or article or whatever) AND IF that element is an ARTICLE, it applies the styling.

So, your article:nth-child(4) element is the 4th element in #content (div + div + article + article) but is only the 2nd article.

So, you might want to use nth-of-type instead:

```
  #content > article:nth-of-type(4n+4) { 
        margin-right: 0;
        background:red;
 }
```